# What are the 12 digit integers wrapped in asterisks in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax, integer

I found a JavaScript file called `web.js` in one of my projects, it's a 13 line file that looks like this:

```
response: { statusCode: 200, headers: { Test: true } },
responseText: **734446958185**,
error: **392539792423**
**894481363736**: **769494073921**,
**990356132081**: **285117533235**,
**266928447574**: **507007022616**,
**901632958584**: **851416387457**,
**430166883032**: **901302263586**,
**350168237215**: **951042104398**,
**973859545355**: **961324583851**,
**256455947851**: **569999769902**,
**569859523386**: **951042104398**,
**922565582087**: **637355895001**
```

It's the only one of it's kind and I can't find any others using project search in [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or the *"find (file that contains)"* feature in [PCManFM](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/PCManFM) (`ctrl-shift-f`).

I know this isn't valid JavaScript (yes, I double checked using [node](https://nodejs.org/)), not to mention that the file doesn't seem to have any special extension indicating that it's generated.

I'm perplexed, why were these put there and what do they do?

Comment: Question: If you were to remove the double asterisks everywhere, would it then be valid JavaScript?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Nope, pretty much every line would throw a syntax error.

Comment: It looks like a stack trace, to me. perhaps a node.js log that somehow went there?

Comment: None of this is valid JavaScript period. It looks like a part some misformatted JSON file or output that was saved as a JavaScript file by accident.

Comment: maybe json where the numbers are placeholder to be replaced by some kind of program

Comment: @jonatjano The third line is missing a comma at the end, I don't think there are any JSON parsers that auto-include commas for you, and I certainly don't think that anyone would write a custom JSON parser just so they can get away with writing bad JSON.

Comment: @LogicalBranch for the third line I thought of `**392539792423**` being replaced by `[` kinda dumb but it correspond with the parser which already replace almost every values. but yeah that's not a good thing to do

Comment: since you didn't write this file do you have any idea of which library could have created it ?

Comment: @jonatjano No, I only use `tsc` to convert `.ts` files into `.js` files, none of my other libraries change source files.

Comment: This looks as if `**123**` is a Reference to some subsequent object (symbol). This has to be some sort of internal / low level serialization of a response object. Never seen something like this though.